# Ignore return variable from an API function in VBA

Tags: vba, ignore, unused-variables

I'm trying to convert some python scripts to VBA and haven't been able to find an equivalent to the underscore method to ignore a return variable from a function I don't want to use.

In python I would do:

[_, MyName, ret] = ETABSModel.PierLabel.GetNameList()

The equivalent statement in VBA is:

ret = ETABSModel.PierLabel.GetNameList(NumberNames, MyName())

How can I ignore the return variable NumberNames in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call a VBA `function` exactly like a `sub`. If you are familiar with other programming languages, you can see a `sub` like a void function - a function that doesn't return anything.

Basically, there are three ways to call a routine in VBA. The first is valid only for functions:

```
Function foo(p1 as Variant, p2 as Variant) as Long
   (...)
   foo = val(p1) + val(p2)
End Function

Sub bar(p1 as Variant, optional p2 as Variant)
   (...)
End Sub


' (1) Call the function and do something with the return value
myVar = foo(2, 4)
myVar = foo(3, 5) + foo(4, 6)
myVar = bar(3, 5)     ' Obviously not possible, "bar" is a Sub
```

The second and third are valid for Subs and Functions. Both are equivalent, it's just a matter of taste. It is sometimes claimed that using `Call` is deprecated, however, I can't find such statement from Microsoft.

```
foo 2, 4   ' Call the Function
bar 2, 4   ' Call the Sub
' Or use Call
Call foo(2, 4)   ' Call the Function
Call bar(2, 4)   ' Call the Sub
```

---

Note that the following syntax is invalid. Either use Call or omit the parenthesis.

```
foo(2, 4)        ' Syntax error
bar(2, 4)        ' Syntax error
```

If you have a sub or function that takes only 1 parameter, the following syntax is valid, however, the parenthesis have a complete different meaning: It will evaluate the value of the parameter and put it on the stack. This will prevent that the value of a parameter that is called by reference is modified by the routine. You can safely assume that in 99% this is done unintentionally.

The VBA editor shows it by adding a space between the routine name and the parameter:

```
bar (2)
```

Using the same syntax for 2 parameters makes it more obvious:
bar (2), (4)